What would the equivalent Latin phrase be for the English phrase “Love of all”?
Google translate says that the English phrase “Love of all” is “amor omnium”.
Is that accurate?  I think Amor means love, but I’m not sure if Omnium means “of all”.
Thank you

Omnium does indeed mean "of all". It can refer to all things, and it can refer to all people, i.e. "love of everyone".

See also this (especially genitive in declension table).

Thank you Figulus and Arfrevwr ♥️
